# add city, country to the account activation email body

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

How can I add User Profile(City and Country) details to the account activation email? Currently I am getting the default joomla message.
Name : 
 email: 
 Username:

I would like to add City, Country to the Email body of the message. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In Registration `Controller` and `model` you can see corresponding functions for saving user data and the email triggering section.

On the registration controller a function name with `register()` calls the model contain `register()`.

Inside the model `register()` is handling the activation email content you can add or remove details from there.

The file path is `components/com_users/controllers/registration.php` and model

registration `components/com_users/models/registration.php`

hope its helps..

Comment: Thank you for the help. I changed the following code to components/com_users/models/registration.php. But it doesn't work. Could you please let me know.   $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
    'COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACTIVATE_WITH_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY',
    $data['sitename'],
    $data['name'],
    $data['email'],
    $data['username'],
    $data['city'],
    $data['country'],
    $data['activate']
   );

Comment: @nav100 Just setting data['city'] .. are not sure to work try to echo those values and make sure it has value .other wise use $_REQUEST['city']